# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in Amazon Kindle Fire

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I know lot of questions regarding this is already posted in stack overflow.Actually I have gone through that and implemented some methods.But still no luck, it's still showing the same error as previous.This is my code.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Activity activity;
int imageArray[];
LayoutInflater inflater;
Typeface tf;
ImageView imageView;
ArrayList<Bitmap> list=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();;
Bitmap bitmap;
public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra) {
    imageArray = imgArra;
    activity = act;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "Times Roman.ttf");
}

public int getCount() {
    return imageArray.length;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    // System.out.println("instantiate.... " + position);
    // ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
    // view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#909090"));
    // view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    // LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    // view.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
    // ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    // return view;
    try {

        View view;

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_starting_screen, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_heading_starting_screen);
        textView.setText(activity.getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.txt_starting_screen)[position]);
        textView.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        imageView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_starting_screen);
                      imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), imageArray[position]));
        bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        list.add(bitmap);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {

    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);


}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
public void clearbitmap(int flag)
{
    if(flag==1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            bitmap=list.get(i);
            bitmap.recycle();
        }


    }
}

}
```

And after searching a lot i have come up with the recycle method but still it's not working.
When I run my app for the first time there is no problem.For the second time it will crash.

I have 5 pages like an intro for the app and when the user is finished with that the application starts.When it starts I set a flag and call the method called clearbitmap and use the recycle method to clear the bitmap.

I already reduced my images size but still not working.But when I am using small resolution images it works.But I don't want that.I am using an Amazon Kindle Fire as my test device.And this problem is only with this device.On rest of the devices it's working fine.

I followed the link given by rajahsekar and I changed my code like this still its crashing

```
     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(),      imageArray[position], options);
         int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
                                 imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(activity.getResources(),imageArray[ position],imageWidth,imageHeight));
```

And calculated the bitmap using this methods

```
  public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

 return inSampleSize;
 } 
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

But still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compress your bitmap and  save it in cache memory. Check below link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.

Remove all your bitmaps from list.

Comment: I am accepting this as answer.Not completely solved my problem however when I changed imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(activity.getResources(),imageArray[ position],200,200)); like this it's start working.Thanks for this link..

Answer (score 1):

A piece of advice, though it may not be answer

```
public void clearbitmap(int flag)
{
    if(flag==1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            bitmap=list.get(i);
            bitmap.recycle();
        }


    }
}
```

instead

```
public void clearbitmap(int flag)
{
    if(flag==1)
    {
        list.removeAll();

    }
}
```

*And more importantly.*

**ArrayList should be used only when you want index wise access. in any other case use LinkedList. In ArrayList, removing an Item is O(n) time and serious penalty where as LinkedList, removing an item is O(1).**

*Since once you deleted an item, in ArrayList all the subsequent items will be bumped by an index, by copying elements. I wouldn't explain in-detail, but you can check this by looking at Collections wiki*